# nginx return a file when request for path

Tags: nginx

As title descript,when i request for "http://example.com/test/poster/",i want to get the real file "/home/vagrant/example/resouces/views/posters.html".

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server_name example.com;
root /home/vagrant/example/public;
index index.html;

location / {
    return 404;
}

location ~ ^/test/poster/?$ {
    default_type text/html;
    index posters.html;
    alias /home/vagrant/example/resouces/views/;
}
```

But when i make the request,i get a 404 response.I search for the nginx error log,i get the info below:

```
2018/10/20 11:54:41 [debug] 4690#4690: *180 http script copy: "/home/vagrant/example/resouces/views/"
2018/10/20 11:54:41 [debug] 4690#4690: *180 open index "/home/vagrant/example/resouces/views/posters.html"
2018/10/20 11:54:41 [debug] 4690#4690: *180 internal redirect: "/test/poster/posters.html?"
2018/10/20 11:54:41 [debug] 4690#4690: *180 rewrite phase: 1
```

Here is my question,when open index,it has find the file,why does it act a internal redirect?

I finally resolve it by using try_files,i just want to know why it dose not work when i use alias with index in one location block.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [index module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html) performs a multistage process.

If the URI ends with a `/` and is found to be a directory within the `location` that is currently processing the request, Nginx will check for a file matching a name in the `index` directive's value.

If a matching file is found, the URI will be changed by appending that name, and the search for a `location` to process the new URI will commence.

In your case, the URI `/test/poster/posters.html` does not match the original `location` and therefore the `posters.html` file is not found.

Comment: "found to be a directory" as pointed,do you mean "/test/poster/" or the dir after alias directive?

Comment: `/test/poster/` is a URI, but the `alias` directive maps it to the directory `/home/vagrant/example/resouces/views/`.

Answer (score 2):

1. If the uri end with '/',nginx will combine index file and alias path as a fullpath index file and to check if this file exist.
2. If it exist,then a internal redirect will commence;if not exist,nginx will check if the alias path is a dir.
3. If the alias path is a dir then nginx will try other index file until it return a 403;If the alias path is not a dir,nginx will directly return a 404.

---

1. If the uri not end with '/',nginx will use the alias path directly.
2. If the alias path is a file but not exist,nginx will return a 404;If the alias path is a dir,nginx will return a 301 with a trailing slash appended with origin uri.